# binding data in a list view from a directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, bind, vb.net-2010

i have a list view :

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
           <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" />
           </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

and i have the link of the images in vb:

```
  Dim dirInfo As string="D:\rbi\images\emoticons\"
  Dim filenames As List(Of String) = dirInfo.GetFiles().[Select](Function(j) j.Name).ToList()
```

i'm getting the link and the filenames from the directory not from a database...so how can i bind these links in the list view to show all the images?

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya inside the application

Comment: Where is the code where are you are binding the `ListView`?

Comment: @KarlAnderson well i'm not binding the listview :) my question is how to bind it with the image path that i have in a list of string...

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury - are you showing a list of images or just one?

Comment: @KarlAnderson it's a list of images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following complete solution:

In aspx page:

```
   <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ToolTip='<%#Eval("Name")%>'/>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:ListView>
```

In aspx.vb page :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Images/emoticons/"))
        Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

        Dim FileList As New List(Of IO.FileInfo)
        'list the names of all files in the specified directory
        For Each dra In diar1
            FileList.Add(dra)
        Next

        ListView1.DataSource = FileList
        ListView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As  System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDataBound
        Dim ImageButton1 As ImageButton
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
            Dim rowView As IO.FileInfo = e.Item.DataItem()
            Dim FileName As String = rowView.Name.ToString()
            ImageButton1 = e.Item.FindControl("ImageButton1")
            ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/emoticons/" & FileName
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to bind the image path to the `ListView` is to have an object which contains `Public` properties to use in `Eval()` bindings, like this:

Code-behind:

```
Public Class ImageBinder
    Public Property path() As String
        Get
            Return m_path
        End Get
        Set
            m_path = Value
        End Set
End Property
Private m_path As String
End Class
```

You will need to have code that will create a list of `ImageBinder` objects now, instead of just a list of strings.

Now in your markup, you can reference the `path` property in your `ListView` markup, like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("path") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Note: This will take care of the binding, but an issue you are going to have to deal with is that if the example path (`D:\rbi\images\emoticons\`) you provided in your question is correct, then it will not work within the confines of ASP.NET, because of security constraints which do not a path outside of the application's virtual directories to be used. You will need to create a virtual directory and use that for the path to the images you wish to show in the `ListView`.